# TS2339 - Can't map request from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, redux

Good day, i have simple component, where I try to get specific data from API (This part works well - I can map data, save it to an array and save it to the 'streams' state in a hook.

The objective is to display the id in the key, category and title.

Error:
[image]

```
  interface IStreams {
        id: number;
        category: string;
        title: string;
      };

     let Streams: React.FC<IStreams> = (props) => {

        const InitialStreamsState = {id: 0, category: '', title: ''}

        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
        const [streams, setStreams] = useState(InitialStreamsState)

        useEffect(() => {
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/stream/getstreams')
            .then(response => {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(streams => {
                console.log(streams);
                const test = streams.map((obj:any) => ({id: obj.id, category: obj.category, title: obj.title}));
                setLoading(true)
                setStreams(test)
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err);
            });
        }, []);

        return (
            <div>
                {loading ?
                    <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                        <div className ="home-header">
                        <h1>Top Streams</h1>
                                {streams.map((id:any, category:any, title:any) => (
                                    <p key={id}>
                                    {title}
                                    {category}
                                    </p>
                                ))}
                        </div>  
                    </Col>
                    </Row>
                    </Container>
                         :
                         <Container>
                         <Row>
                             <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                             <div className ="home-header">
                             <h1>Loading</h1>
                             </div>  
                         </Col>
                         </Row>
                         </Container>
                         }
            </div>
        );
      }
```

---

I don't know what i did but this piece of code works:

```
interface IStreams {
    id: number;
    category: string;
    title: string;
  };

let Streams: React.FC<IStreams> = (props) => {

    const InitialStreamsState = {id: 0, title:'', description:''}

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    //const [streams, setStreams] = useState([InitialStreamsState])
    const [streams, setStreams] = useState([InitialStreamsState])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(API + '/stream/getstreams')
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(streams => {
            //const result = streams.map((obj:any) => ({id: obj.id, category: obj.category, title: obj.title}));
            const result = streams.map((obj:any) => ({id: obj.id, title: obj.title, description:obj.description}));
            console.log(result)
            setLoading(true)
            setStreams(result)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {loading ?
                <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                    <div className ="home-header">
                    <h1>Top Streams</h1>
                            {streams.map((stream) => (
                                <div key = {stream.id}>
                               <h1> {stream.title}</h1>
                               <p>{stream.description}</p>
                                <Link to={{ 
                                        pathname: `/stream/${stream.id}`,
                                        state: {id: stream.id}
                                    }}> 
                                    <button className ="primary-button">View</button></Link>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                    </div>  
                </Col>
                </Row>
                </Container>
                     :
                     <Container>
                     <Row>
                         <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                         <div className ="home-header">
                         <h1>Loading</h1>
                         </div>  
                     </Col>
                     </Row>
                     </Container>
                     }
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It clearly says map property does not exist type steam. Now in your case whats the type of stream??  If its type is array then fine. It think in your case its type is Object. In Js there is no native map function on Object. It has only on Array. So TS os throwing error.

Comment: ok, how can i convert Obj to Array in this case?

Comment: Its pretty simple !!  you can use library like lodash for all utilities functions or with native Js first get the keys of stream and then map like : 
 Object.keys(stream).map(key => ( { id : stream[key].id })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `.map` function on an object type as declared in `IStreams`. Try to convert it to array of objects instead. You can try like below, calling the interface for object as `IStream` and expecting array of `IStream`. Also `InitialStreamsState` should be an array of objects.

```
interface IStream {
  id: number;
  category: string;
  title: string;
};

let Streams: React.FC<IStream[]> = (props) => {
  const InitialStreamsState = [{id: 0, category: '', title: ''}];

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [streams, setStreams] = useState(InitialStreamsState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/stream/getstreams')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((responseStreams as IStream[]) => {
      console.log(responseStreams);
      const test = responseStreams.map(stream => ({id: stream.id, category: stream.category, title: stream.title}));
      setLoading(true);
      setStreams(test);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ?
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col xs="6" sm="4">
              <div className ="home-header">
                <h1>Top Streams</h1>
                  {streams.map((id:any, category:any, title:any) => (
                    <p key={id}>
                      {title}
                      {category}
                    </p>
                  ))}
                </div>  
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        :
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                <div className ="home-header">
                  <h1>Loading</h1>
                </div>  
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```